# How to generate characters in different encodings using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to generate characters in different encodings using MySQL.

My script looks like this:

```
SET @id := 678;
SELECT
    @id,
    CHAR(@id USING utf32),
    CHAR(@id USING utf16),
    CHAR(@id USING utf8),
    HEX(CHAR(@id USING utf32)),
    HEX(CHAR(@id USING utf16)),
    HEX(CHAR(@id USING utf8))
```

My expected result is:

```
678
ʦ
ʦ
ʦ
000002A6
02A6
CAA6
```

What i actually get:

```
678
ʦ
ʦ
            <-- Questionable
000002A6
02A6
02          <-- Questionable
```

**Is there a way to do this in MySQL?**

### Answere

Thanks at [lanzz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10816480/113154).

```
SET @id = 45678;
SELECT
    @id,
    CHAR(@id USING utf32),
    CONVERT(CHAR(@id USING utf32) USING utf16),
    CONVERT(CHAR(@id USING utf32) USING utf8),
    HEX(CHAR(@id USING utf32)),
    HEX(CONVERT(CHAR(@id USING utf32) USING utf16)),
    HEX(CONVERT(CHAR(@id USING utf32) USING utf8));
```

Result:

```
45678
뉮
뉮
뉮
0000B26E
B26E
EB89AE
```

Comment: Only the conversion to UTF8 requires the `CONVERT()` part; as you have seen yourself, `CHAR()` is enough to produce UTF16 and UTF32.

Comment: Try @id = 66600 which gives different results. Strange :-T

Comment: Ah, yes, `CONVERT()` is still needed for surrogate pairs.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? Sounds very interesting.

Comment: In this case, Wikipedia. If it wasn't in the wiki page, it would at least have links to the actual standards there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `CONVERT(CHAR(678 USING UTF16) USING UTF8)`. The `CHAR()` call will convert your unicode character code into an actual string, and `CONVERT()` will convert that string into actual UTF8.

Comment: Oops, should have `USING` instead of comma.

Answer (score 0):

The byte sequence `0x02A6` (decimal 678) in UTF-8 is [invalid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences); the first byte decodes as [`U+0002`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0002/index.htm), but the second byte has no decoding.

Comment: My question is: is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: @eisberg: Is there a way to do *what*?  Converting that byte sequence to UTF-8 is meaningless.

Comment: I want to convert any integer to the equivalent character in UTF-32, UTF-16, UTF-8 and so on.

Comment: @eisberg: But it's not possible to convert *any* integer to UTF-8.  Not all byte sequences/integers are *valid* UTF-8 encodings.

Comment: I know what you are aiming at, but converting in most other ways (like mb_*-functions in PHP) will return an empty string or some other clue, that this specific character cannot be converted.

Comment: @eisberg: Perhaps I have misunderstood.  Are you simply trying to get the [`U+02A6`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a6/index.htm) character as a UTF-8 encoded string?  Or are you (as I had originally thought) trying to decode the integer 678 as UTF-8?

Comment: Think of @id as input variable (type integer) and I want to get the equivalent n-th character in a specific encoding. Most likely the character should be the same but with different encoding.

Comment: @eisberg: I'm not sure what you mean by "*the n-th character*", but I suspect [@lanzz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10816480/623041) is what you want.